# Problem with publishing the applet

Tags: java, applet

I am trying to publish the applet on the web. I know the syntax of the `<applet>` tag, and the icons for the buttons I am using are in the same folder as all of the classes. I don't know what is wrong. Here is the code:

```
<applet code="Bomb.class" codebase="..//..//build//classes" width="650" height="450">
<p>This requires a java-enabled browser</p>
</applet>
```

Please help. :(

Comment: please show us some code

Comment: @thejh you mean the HTML markup?

Comment: ok here it is: <applet code="Bomb.class" codebase="..//..//build//classes" width="650" height="450"><p>This requires a java-enabled browser.</p></applet>

Comment: add code into question, also the class code

Comment: Some error messages would be nice too.

Comment: @fireshadow52 Could you edit your question and add the applet tag with code format and the code you are using to read the images?

Comment: @org.life.java What do you mean by the class code?

Comment: @Enrique I can give you the source code for the applet tag. However, the code for the images is extremely long.

Comment: @OrangeDog I didn't get any error messages, so :|

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
Image myImage= getImage(getDocumentBase(),"img.jpg");
ImageIcon imgIcon = new ImageIcon(myImage);
```

Comment: Sorry I wasn't being very clear. I need the 'ImageIcon' tag, as I am using icons for my buttons.

Comment: I have tried that and it compiled without any errors. However, when I write the <applet> tag and view it in a web browser, it just comes up as this blank space with a red 'X'.

Comment: Long time. I finally fixed it! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

While publishing an applet, you really should create a `jar` file with the Applet's classes and resources (such as images) in it.  Then you can use `Class`'s [`getResource`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource%28java.lang.String%29) to get a `Url` for it, like this:

```
ImageIcon myImage = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("/img.jpg"));
```

The `/` is necessary because of how `Class`'s `getResource` works.

Comment: How would I create a .jar file? (I am using NetBeans to write the code)

Comment: If you're using an IDE, they usually have an Export to JAR file.  Otherwise, there is a command line tool to create one that ships with the JDK... I believe the correct syntax is `jar cvf myApplet.jar *` to create a jar named myApplet.jar file containing everything in the current directory.  You can also put non-code files in subdirectories before you create the jar.

Comment: The .jar file is now created.

Comment: I think I am using the wrong class. I am doing <applet code="Bomb.class" archive="aBomb.jar" width="650" height="450">